# Androidannotations + Android Studio ( almost working )

Tags: android, android-studio

This is something I'm trying to figure out. How do you make both run **without** using Gradle or Maven to compile the source files.

What works:
I've done the following steps:

- set up the Annotations processor for Android Studio to point at androidannotations-2.7.1
- added a new library inside my project's module named androidannotations-api-2.7.1

I can tell it works because Android Studio automatically does the right imports for me when I press Alt+Enter.

**Problem:** during compilation I get the following message:

> Unexpected error. Please report an issue on AndroidAnnotations, with
>   the following content: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find
>   the AndroidManifest.xml file, going up from path
>   [/home/user/Work/FailAnnotationTryProject/build/classes/production/main/generated]
>   found using dummy file
>   [file:///home/user/Work/FailAnnotationTryProject/build/classes/production/main/generated/dummy1382376292025.java]
>   (max atempts: 10)

I have checked my Facets -> Manifest file path and it is right.

Has someone got any suggestion or better a solution?

Comment: The error suggests that you report the issue on AndroidAnnotations, with the content you've got here...seems like a worthy start to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I faced with same problem and fixed it by changing Settings->Compiler-> Annotation Processors->"Store generated sources relative to:" to "Model content root".

[image: Java Compiler Annotation Processors]

I hope it will help.

Comment: @Pierry did you find other solution?

Comment: yeah, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705318/android-annotations-with-android-studio/27079797#27079797