# Unable to build Android project in Android Studio 3.1 using Gradle 3.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-annotations

Firstly, I am totally new to Android platform so please excuse me if I am committing any mistake. I am trying to build an android project using Gradle 3.0.0 version and using Google Android annotations api. Below is my project `build.gradle` file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my app `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.demo.see.android.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 22
    versionName "3.2.0"
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    /*javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath true
        }
    }*/

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}


/*apt {
  arguments {
    androidManifestFile ${variant.processResources.manifestFile}
    resourcePackageName "com.demo.see.android.app"
  }
}*/



ext.daggerVersion = '1.0.0';
ext.androidAnnotationsVersion = '2.4';
def AAVersion = '3.3.2'

//def AAVersion = "4.4.0"

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//annotationProcessor 'com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:2.4'
//compileOnly 'com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:2.4'
//implementation 'com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:2.4'
compile group: 'com.googlecode.androidannotations', name: 'androidannotations', version: '2.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:2.5.1'

compileOnly 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.inject:guice:2.0-no_aop'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:11.0'
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.31'
implementation 'org.roboguice:roboguice:1.1.2'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.5'
testImplementation 'com.pivotallabs:robolectric:1.2'
testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.1'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.8.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
//annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
//implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"*/

//implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'--
//annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'

/* implementation "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
compile "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:${androidAnnotationsVersion}:api"

/*apt "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
compile "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
annotationProcessor "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
apt "com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
compile "com.squareup.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"*/

//compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
//annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
}


/*android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
aptOutput = file("${project.buildDir}/source/generated/${variant.dirName}")
println "****************************"
println "variant: ${variant.name}"
println "manifest:  ${variant.processResources.manifestFile}"
println "aptOutput:  ${aptOutput}"
println "****************************"

variant.javaCompile.doFirst {
    println "*** compile doFirst ${variant.name}"
    aptOutput.mkdirs()
    variant.javaCompile.options.compilerArgs += [
            '-processorpath', configurations.apt.getAsPath(),
            '-AandroidManifestFile=' + variant.processResources.manifestFile,
            '-s', aptOutput
    ]
  }
}*/
```

the exceptions revolves around the annotations usage.
Note: The commented part mentioned in app.gradle are parts of trail and errors as I tried multiple permutation and combinations and got several exceptions like

```
`Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
 Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation 
 processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
 - androidannotations-2.5.1.jar 
 (com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:2.5.1)`
```

currently, I am getting this error

```
Error: Unexpected error. 
Please report an issue on AndroidAnnotations, with the following content: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file, 
going up from path [/home/bhargav/See/see-android/app/build/generated/source/apt/debug] found using dummy file [file:///home/bhargav/See/see-android/app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/dummy1513070341263.java] (max atempts: 10)
```

Apart from that I have also enabled annotation processors from File> other Setting > default setting > compiler >annotation processing

I have gone through many links like below mentioned

[Android studio + Gradle + Android Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910603/android-studio-gradle-android-annotations/17999249#17999249)

[Androidannotations + Android Studio ( almost working )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501022/androidannotations-android-studio-almost-working)

even if after figuring out a workaround way via some configuration tuning I got error like `could not found symbol Eactivity & robojuice` on lines of

```
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.RoboGuice;
```

Version which I am using in this project

- Android studio - 3.0.1
- Gradle - 3.0.0
- Java 1.8 (Android recomendation)

folder structure

[image]

Comment: have you tried updating gradle? current version is like 4.4.1. let me know please